# python re.search matching all from csv.reader?

Tags: python, csv

I have an example script where I am searching for `[Data]` in a line. The odd thing is that it always matches when reading the file with `csv.reader`. See code below. Any ideas?

```
#!/opt/Python-2.7.3/bin/python
import csv
import re
import os

content = '''# foo
[Header],,
foo bar,blah,

[Settings]
Yadda,yadda

[Data],,
Alfa,Beta,Gamma,Delta,Epsilon
One,Two,Tree,Four,Five
'''
f1 = open("/tmp/file", "w")
print >>f1, content
f1.close()

f = open("/tmp/file", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)
found_csv = 0
mycsv = []
for l in reader:
    line = str(l)
    if line == '[]': continue
    if re.search("[Data]", line):
        print line
        found_csv = 1
    if found_csv:
        mycsv.append(l)
```

Prints:

```
['[Header]', '', '']
['foo bar', 'blah', '']
['[Settings]']
['Yadda', 'yadda']
['[Data]', '', '']
['Alfa', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta', 'Epsilon']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find a line with string `[Data]` (with brackets), you should add `\` before brackets in pattern:

```
#if re.search("[Data]", line):
if re.search("\[Data\]", line):
```

Pattern `[Data]` without backslashes means that you want search any character from set (`D` or `a` or `t`) in line.

Comment: @JustinBarber your example matches because `'[Data]'` contains at least one of `'D'`, `'a'`, `'t'` `re.search('[Data]', 'a')` matches as well.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The error in the original code is how you set `founc_csv` the first time it finds data, and then never resets it to 0. That or you can simply remove the need for it entirely:

```
mycsv = []
for l in reader:
    line = str(l)
    if line == '[]': 
        continue
    elif "[Data]" in line:
        print line
        mycsv.append(l)
```

-- Original answer --

re is treating `"[Data]"` as a regular expression. You actually don't even need re at all in this case an simply can change it to:

```
if "[Data]" in line:
```

However if you are going to do more advanced regular expression based searching, just make sure to [format them properly](https://pythex.org/):

```
if re.search(r'\[Data\]', line):
```